# ROR - Enums not getting loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, activerecord

For the past few months, we are facing an issue with our rails application, Whenever we give a new deployment 5 out of 10 times the enums for some objects doesn't get loaded resulting in throwing an error.

Overview: In our application, we have a user model in which there is an enum status (active, in_active), in_active means that the user has left our platform, So while authenticating the user we check that `if user.status == :active` then we allow the user to proceed or else throw the error that the account has been deactivated. Whenever a new deployment is given the code throws this error for all users regardless they are active or in_active, to further debug this we started logging the state of the object at the time this error is thrown, After logging, we found that for our user model enum status is not being loaded resulting in this error because at that time status was nil.

Code snippet where we are facing this error.

```
enum status: [:in_active, :active]
```

```
def authenticate_user(auth_token)
  @session = Session.for_token(auth_token)
  render_error_json('auth_failed') and return unless @session
  @user = @session.user 
  update_state_to_loggly # logging the current state of session and user objects
  return true if (@user.status == :active && @session.status == :active) # successfully authenticated
  render_error_json(267) and return # Your account has been disabled error
end
```

This is the log before and after the server is restarted.

```
before: "user_obj":{"id":1,"status":null,"status_db":null}
after:  "user_obj":{"id":1,"status":active,"status_db":active}
```

If we just restart the server then everything works fine.

Can someone please point out what could be the issue here?

Comment: What error is thrown exactly?

Comment: It's a custom error that we throw saying Your account has been deactivated.

Comment: Can you show the relevant parts of your authentication code (maybe the 3 lines before the error and 3 lines after) and also how the enum field is defined on your user class? It's quite hard to understand what may be happening just by reading your question.

Comment: Do you have a default value for your enum column? Bytw the word is `inactive` - not `in active`.

Comment: I have updated the code snippet in the question itself.